# Как оформить вопросительное предложение, включающее прямую речь

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Правильно ли я поставил знаки препинания в вопросительных предложениях, включающих прямую речь?

Пример 1. Слова автора содержат вопрос, прямая речь - повествовательное предложение.

**Где вы были, когда он сказал: "Меня зовут Роберт"?**

Пример 2. Слова автора содержат вопрос, прямая речь - восклицательное предложение.

**Где вы были, когда он кричал: "Я так больше не могу!"**

Хотелось бы получить объяснение, ссылку на источник, правило, которое можно было бы применять в разных случаях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Где вы были, когда он сказал: "Меня зовут Роберт"?

2) Где вы были, когда он кричал: "Я так больше не могу!"?

После кавычек ставится знак вопроса, относящийся ко всему предложению.

**Правило**

[Розенталь, § 48. Прямая речь после слов автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=156#pp156)

**Вопросительный и восклицательный знаки, а также многоточие ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками**, а точка — после них. Наконец я ей сказал: «Хочешь, пойдём прогуляться на вал?» (Л.).

Но во втором предложении вместо точки ставится вопросительный знак.

Answer (score 2):

Где вы были, когда он сказал: "Меня зовут Роберт"?

Где вы были, когда он кричал: "Я так больше не могу!"?

Comment: хотелось бы получить объяснение, ссылку на источник, правило, которое можно было бы применять в разных случаях.

Comment: в первом случае вопрос в словах автора, поэтому знак вопроса относится к словам автора, а не к прямой речи. Во втором случае так же о вопросительном знаке, а в прямой речи появляется восклицание, поэтому в ней - восклицательный знак.